# HTML datalist is not working since Android 8 or higher in WebView

Tags: android, html, cordova, google-chrome, html-datalist

[HTML datalist element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) is not working since Android 8 in Chrome WebView (Hybrid Apps). However, it's working with previous Android versions.

#### Problem

If I try to open or type in an HTML datalist nothing happens. It behaves like an HTML input. So, you cannot list your options, search or autocomplete. The popup doesn't show up as well.

#### How to reproduce it?

Add this to a default Cordova/Phonegap/Ionic example and open it on Android 8 or higher.

```
<label for="ice-cream-choice">Choose a flavor:</label>
<input list="ice-cream-flavors" id="ice-cream-choice" name="ice-cream-choice" />

<datalist id="ice-cream-flavors">
  <option value="Chocolate">
  <option value="Coconut">
  <option value="Mint">
  <option value="Strawberry">
  <option value="Vanilla">
</datalist>
```

#### Tested

1. Huawei P7 L10 with Android 5 (working)
2. BQ Aquaris U Lite with Android 7 (working)
3. Samsung Galaxy A5 2017 with Android 8 (not working)
4. Xiaomi Mi Redmi Note 6 Pro with Android 8 (not working)
5. Xiaomi Mi A1 (Android One) with Android 9 (not working)

#### I use this Chrome version (WebView)

"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; SM-A520F Build/R16NW; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 **Chrome/73.0.3683.90** Mobile Safari/537.36"

#### Question

Is there any configuration on Android 8 or higher to make datalist works again?

Comment: https://github.com/mfranzke/datalist-polyfill

Comment: As I am not good at English, I am sorry for not being a clear answer.
It may be Chromium issue. See : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=662828